# Android 3.1 Intellij doesn't support code complete with lower case

Tags: android, android-studio

Prior to updating my android studio to 3.1, the code complete was not case sensitive. But after the update it has become case sensitive i.e. if I type `main` it used to correctly propose `MainActivity` but with 3.1 it only shows `MainActivity`if I type `Main`with captial "M".

Is there a way to achieve this in 3.1. I have tried to scan through settings but didn't yield any result.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly go to Setting
from Setting open Editor --->General --> Code Completion -- > change Case Sensitive Completion to None.

Answer (score 0):

Added Visualization for @Rohit answer:

[image: code completion]